# spotfire column value with images

Tags: spotfire

Is it possible to add images in the cell values in cross tab.

I am trying to replicate the attached designed in excel.

**I am able to do it for one column**, for example in the attached I can create it for East by creating a calculated categorical field but not sure how to fit in the other regions .

[image: screen shot of current excel version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not with a cross table. For this, you need to use a [Graphical Table](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/gt/gt_what_is_a_graphical_table.htm)